# Calculating heat loss to environment while an object is being heated up using Newton's Law of Cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

I was experimenting with Newton's Law of Cooling lately, and I was wondering, how would one go about calculating heat loss to environment, while an object is being actively heated?
Let's say I had a boiler, whose constant of cooling k I know. I measure the temperature at t=0 - it's equal to the ambient temperature (A). I then measure the temperature some time later (at time t), it's equal to T(t).

I know the mass of water, its specific heat, ambient temperature, final temperature, time passed, as well as the constant k.
I'm trying to work out a concept so I'm completely disregarding radiated heat, air heating up etc.

I set up this differential equation, trying to find energy lost to environment:

```
dT/dt = m*c*dT/dt - k(T-A)
```

Where `m*c*dT` could be rewritten as dQ.
But then I realized I messed up the units and I have no idea how to fix it (and I only know basic calculus).

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: You would also need to take into account the heat capacities of the boiler materials that get heated up in addition to the water contained in the boiler.

Comment: You should study the answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/677258/a-room-with-a-heater-in-contact-with-walls-as-a-heat-sink/677327#677327 It deals with the same type of problem: something is internally heated while losing convection heat to the env, (Newton's law of cooling) Also, don't used that wretched $k$ thingy. Use the full Law of cooling instead.

Comment: [Cooling correction](https://spark.iop.org/cooling-corrections)

Answer (score 1):

For an object that is heated internally with a constant power $P$ and losing heat convectively to its environment, the heat balance in an infinitesimal time interval is:

$$\text{Heat generated = Heat retained + Heat lost}$$

or:

$$P\mathrm{d}t=Mc\mathrm{d}T(t)+hA\left[T(t)-T_A\right]\mathrm{d}t$$

Divide both sides by $\mathrm{d}t$ and make a substitution:

$$\Theta=T(t)-T_A$$

That gets:

$$P=Mc\frac{\mathrm{d}\Theta}{\mathrm{d}t}+hA\Theta$$
$$Mc\Theta'+hA\Theta=P$$
$$\Theta'+\alpha \Theta=\frac{P}{Mc}$$

This a 1st order ODE, separable. Solve it to find $T(t)$.

> and I only know basic calculus

You can use [Wolfram alpha  (solution link)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28t%29%2Bay%28t%29%3DP) to  solve the ODE.

---

Another interesting point to make is, what is the maximum temperature $T_{\infty}$ the object will reach?

Well, at some point the power $P$ will equal the convection losses. The temperature can then no longer increase:

$$P=hA(T_{\infty}-T_A)$$

$$\Rightarrow T_{\infty}=T_A+\frac{P}{hA}$$

Comment: What if I don't know the power or if it's not constant?

Comment: If $P \neq \text{constant}$ but $P=f(t)$ then the ODE can still be solved,  if $f(t)$ is reasonably well-behaved.